# Git bash asks SSH key which I forgot

Tags: git-bash, ssh-keys

I tried installing something using Git Bash with the command,
`leanproject get mathematics_in_lean`
but I got the prompt
`Please provide password for encrypted SSH private key:`
I however don't remember ever making an SSH-key for this (although this does not mean I never did) and the password is not my password of my GitHub user. I already informed on a lean platform and there they told this is more likely a Git thing than a Lean thing. Does anyone have an idea on how to retrieve the password or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the password is impossible, and that's the idea of (SSH-keys with a passphrase)

But because you said you don't remember doing that; then maybe the remote repo is defined as `git@github.com:username/reponame` so it will try available SSH keys you have. One possible solution is to amend it to https

for example, for a remote like this:

```
$ git remote -v
  origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git (fetch)
  origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git (push)
```

you can do the following to convert it to https:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

after that, any fetch, pull, or push will not require SSH

OR

you can reset your SSH key in github https://github.com/settings/keys